# How to insert List<Object> into ObjectDB

Tags: java, jpa

I have a class called "Matricula" which contains a String and a List

```
@Id
private String dni;

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = Asignatura.class)
private List<Asignatura> asignaturas;
```

The problem is that when I try to insert "Matricula" into the database, it only gets the @Id of "Asignatura", the rest of it is null.

[ObjectDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOGE3.png)

I've checked the "Matricula" before the insert and its all good. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have getters in class 'Matricula' and 'Asignatura' ?

Comment: Yes both for "asignaturas" and "dni"

Comment: And in class `Asignatura` ?

Comment: Yes. It is weird because if I do @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Asignatura.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL), the first time it works just fine, but if I try to add another "Matricula", it says that the "Asignatura" @Id already exists.

Comment: Problem solved. Had to use merge() instead of persist().